# First time gulp user, can't build skeleton project. I don't see anything else on the web with this error

Tags: node.js, express, gulp

Hi this is my first time using gulp, and I'm trying to use typescript/gulp/express to form a RESTful web service.

I found a skeleton project for this but I get an error when I try to build it.

Here's a link to the project:
https://github.com/idanov/express-ts-rest

```
Kevins-Mac-Pro:express-ts-rest kevincmanning$ gulp buildAll
{ file: undefined,
  start: undefined,
  length: undefined,
  messageText: 'Failed to parse file \'src/tsconfig.json\': text.charCodeAt is not a function.',
  category: 1,
  code: 5014 }
{ file: undefined,
  start: undefined,
  length: undefined,
  messageText: 'Failed to parse file \'tests/tsconfig.json\': text.charCodeAt is not a function.',
  category: 1,
  code: 5014 }
[00:59:23] Using gulpfile ~/Projects/express-ts-rest/gulpfile.js
[00:59:23] Starting 'build'...
[00:59:23] 'build' errored after 10 ms
[00:59:23] TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of null
    at DestroyableTransform.Readable.pipe (/Users/kevincmanning/Projects/express-ts-rest/node_modules/vinyl-fs/node_modules/readable-stream/lib/_stream_readable.js:516:7)
    at Gulp.<anonymous> (/Users/kevincmanning/Projects/express-ts-rest/gulpfile.js:35:10)
    at module.exports (/Users/kevincmanning/Projects/express-ts-rest/node_modules/orchestrator/lib/runTask.js:34:7)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runTask (/Users/kevincmanning/Projects/express-ts-rest/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:273:3)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator._runStep (/Users/kevincmanning/Projects/express-ts-rest/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:214:10)
    at Gulp.Orchestrator.start (/Users/kevincmanning/Projects/express-ts-rest/node_modules/orchestrator/index.js:134:8)
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/gulp-cli/lib/versioned/^3.7.0/index.js:46:20
    at nextTickCallbackWith0Args (node.js:415:9)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:344:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:443:11)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project runs fine under Ubuntu. However, there is an issue with the `gulp-tsb` package for OS X which causes your problem. You can follow up the progress at https://github.com/jrieken/gulp-tsb/issues/34

Meanwhile if you want to hack around it, just edit `node_modules/gulp-tsb/lib/index.js` on line 11 by replacing `fs_1.readFileSync(path, undefined);` with `fs_1.readFileSync(path, 'utf-8');`.

Comment: Thanks for following up! Giving this a try now.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Steps to Run the tasks:

1. First download the project
2. Navigate to the project folder in terminal and do `npm install`
3. After successfull installation do `npm install -g gulp` This installs gulp globally.
4. Run a gulp task. For example at terminal on the project folder, `gulp build` executes the gulp task called build.

Comment: I understand how to run the gulp task. The problem is the gulp task fails with this error and I don't understand why and can't find anyone with the same problem. I tried building from scratch on a different mac computer but no luck there either. Same error.